# Scrapy gives URLError: <urlopen error timed out>

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I have a scrapy program I am trying to get off the ground but I can't get my code to execute it always comes out with the error below.

I can still visit the site using the `scrapy shell` command so I know the Url's and stuff all work.

Here is my code

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from Malscraper.items import MalItem

class MalSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'Mal'
  allowed_domains = ['www.website.net']
  start_urls = ['http://www.website.net/stuff.php?']
  rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(
        allow=['//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/a[1]']),
        callback='parse_item',
        follow=True)
  ]

  def parse_item(self, response):
    mal_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/table/tr/td[2]/')

    for mal in mal_list:
      item = MalItem()
      item['name'] = mal.xpath('a[1]/strong/text()').extract_first()
      item['link'] = mal.xpath('a[1]/@href').extract_first()

      yield item
```

Edit: Here is the trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Edit2:

So with the scrapy `shell command` I am able to manipulate my responses but I just noticed that the same exact error comes up again when visiting the site

Edit3:

I am now finding that the error shows up on EVERY website I use the `shell command` with, but I am able to manipulate the response still.

Edit4: 
So how do I verify I am atleast receiving a response from Scrapy when running the `crawl command`?
Now I don't know if its my code that is the reason my logs turns up empty or the error ?

Here is my settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'Malscraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Malscraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Malscraper.spiders'
FEED_URI = 'logs/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv'
FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'
```

Comment: can you post traceback with exception?

Comment: also are you sure your url returns proper responses? perhaps website just times out? which website are your crawling

Comment: I am a 100% sure it returns a proper response, I used to the shell command to verify my xpaths.

Comment: Can you share the actual url so we can test?

Comment: this is not scrapy error this looks like boto error \Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py your error is boto trying to connect somewhere and timing out it's not scrapy spider

Comment: Scrapy does not use urllib at any point

Comment: it really seems like there is something crazy in your installation can you try opening file "C:\Users\2015\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py"  inserting: from pdb import set_trace; set_trace() on line 210 and checking where boto tries to connect? you should have urllib request object there so you should get urls it tries to request

Comment: @PawelMiech <urllib2.Request instance at 0x0000000004E90788>

Comment: what url it is requesting

Comment: @PawelMiech here it is looks like an aws ip
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81554/discussion-between-pawel-miech-and-grasshopper).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's an open scrapy issue for this problem: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1054

Although it seems to be just a warning on other platforms.

You can disable the S3DownloadHandler (that is causing this error) by adding to your scrapy settings:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
  's3': None,
}
```

Comment: is there a way to change this in Scrapy package than set this each time in the scrapy script?

Comment: Do you mean setting it globally on your machine so it works for all projects? I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

you can also remove `boto` from the optional packages adding:

```
from scrapy import optional_features
optional_features.remove('boto')
```

as suggested in this [issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1099)

Answer (score 1):

This is very annoying. What is happening is that you have Null credentials and boto decides to populate them for you from a metadata server (if it exists) using `_populate_keys_from_metadata_server()`. See [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/2d7796a625f9596cbadb7d00c0198e5ed84631ed/boto/provider.py#L379) and [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/b016c07d834df5bce75141c4b9d2f3d30352e1b8/boto/utils.py#L421). If you don't run in an EC2 instance, or something that runs a metadata server (listening in the auto-magic IP: 169.254.169.254), the attempt timeouts. This was ok and quiet since scrapy handles the exception [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/s3.py#L47), but unfortunately, boto started logging it [here](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/b016c07d834df5bce75141c4b9d2f3d30352e1b8/boto/utils.py#L224) thus, the annoying message. Apart from disabling the s3 as said before... which looks a bit scary, you can achieve similar results by just setting the credentials to an empty string.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ""
```